# Why are there so many meta questions on Meta Stack Overflow that belong here?

Tags: support, meta, per-site-meta

I've noticed that on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://www.meta.stackoverflow.com), there are lots of questions that should be here on Meta Stack Exchange instead. Why is this?

Comment: And vice versa, there are a lot of old questions here that really belong on Meta.SO. Many are already closed as "off-topic" (pertains to only one site).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, discoverability. There are more links from Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Overflow than directly to Meta Stack Exchange:

- Currently, there are two [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) MSE questions in the sidebar widget, but four MSO questions. Sometimes, the ratio is even more in favor of MSO.
- The 'hamburger' on the right contains a link to MSO right under the current site, for MSE you have to dig deeper in the dropdown.
- Most (all?) links to 'meta' in the Stack Overflow [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=meta) point to MSO, not MSE.
- Meta-type questions posted on the main Stack Overflow site can be migrated by regular users to Meta Stack Overflow, not Meta Stack Exchange. This implies people searching on Stack Overflow for site support might be redirected to Meta Stack Overflow via a migration stub.

So new users are more likely to discover Meta Stack Overflow first, and ask their question there. They might not even know, or not be interested in, the entirely network of Stack Exchange sites at all.

Also, while some questions might receive better answers here than on MSO (or vice versa), being on-topic here doesn't mean it's off-topic on MSO. In fact, the [What is "meta" on Meta Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) is almost identical to the [What is "meta" here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).